# Drupal's JS and CSS optimization error

Tags: css, optimization, drupal, configuration, javascript

I started getting errors after I turned on Drupal's performance improvements which pack all the CSS and JS files into single files. The error looks like this:

> The selected file /tmp/fileO4fjBF
>   could not be uploaded, because the
>   destination
>   js/js_8a69e612be02242c2866a4a19223bd12.js
>   is not properly configured.

I'm not sure how I should configure my server for this to work correctly. There is nothing in the documentation about this.

Comment: Things like this are typically permission issues. Ensure your save path is writable by PHP/Drupal

Comment: @Kevin chmod 777 is rarely the correct solution. At least tell people to use chmod 755 and look at the user/group on the directory and fix that if necessary. 777 is just not secure at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check you ' Site Configuration > Files' settings or the report. If it is a file permission issue (or maybe a missing folder) it should be apparent from one of those two places.

Often the report or files-settings also supply information on how to remedy the problem.

Comment: In my case I had a typo in the temporary path which I put in my settings.php as I did not remember that it was also defined in the `File system` settings.

Comment: Adding temporary paths in your settings.php can make great sense if the location differs from your local environment to the server :-)